# HTTP not redirecting to HTTPS, Router or Firewall Issue?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, firewall, routing

I manage an application server in a different department from IT and since they implemented a new firewall as part of emergency maintenance, users are having issues accessing the web app(Blackboard).

When you configure Blackboard and install it, it automatically creates the website in IIS, and creates two headers binding https, port 443, on IP address *, and another with http, port 80, IP address field is blank.

Before this new firewall, browsers would resolve either port 80 or port 443 fine. Requests to the port 80 for the website would return the secure(HTTPS) page. The issue now is that students and faculty are having issues getting to the page when they're off campus because our network/the firewall(I believe anyway)is not redirecting the port 80 request to the 443 port.

Basically, when users try to access the site, and just type in the URL without any `http://` or `https://` header in the address bar, their browser assumes a port 80 request and tries to connect to `http://www.appserver.com` thus our network isn't delivering it back. If a student puts in `https://` manually in front of the URL, the app server loads perfectly fine.

So is there a firewall, networking, or server OS issue? I haven't touched anything before or after their maintenance and that's when the issues started. If it is, what needs to be changed and what should I tell the IT guys to look into to see if they can identify the issue?

Comment: Can you test to see if a connection is coming through on port 80 from the outside? It sounds like the firewall is simply blocking port 80, so the request is never getting to the web server to get rewritten.

Comment: I've tested multiple times from external sources, https:// works whereas http:// does not.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. Can you see a connection when you come in to http:// ? I.e. drop a sniffer in place, can you see packets on it coming in from an external connection? You have to figure out *where* the http:// bits are broken, not just that they are broken (which you've already figured out).

Comment: Yes, using a packet sniffer I can see the incoming connection from an external source. The server responds with a bunch of TCP Retransmissions, HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily.

Comment: On the client side in your testing, can you see the 302 response coming back from port 80?